# Cannot preview shapefiles uploaded via REST in Geoserver

Tags: c#, esri, geoserver

I have managed to get my shapefile archives to publish to Geoserver via the REST API using the helpful online cURL examples. Though I had to translate them to C# and the HttpWebRequest class. Now, everything works fine insofar as I can upload the file and then request it in any format under the WFS option in the preview format dropdown:

[image]

[image]

However, I can't preview it in OpenLayers or request any of the WMS formats (rasters, etc). Notice the null in the request URL, which I assume is the problem, but it's probably a symptom of a larger problem.

[image]

[image]

Now, my upload code is functioning properly, but here it is in case you were wondering. Or maybe I need to perform a second call.

*Side note: Yes, I know I'm essentially duplicating the authentication, but the WebRequest sends a non-authenticated first request and this is the only way to get around that.*:

```
public bool UploadShapeFile(string workspace, string newStoreName, byte[] fileContents)
    {

        byte[] localShapeFile = fileContents;

        String sUrl = GEOSERVER_HOST + "rest/workspaces/" + workspace + "/datastores/" + newStoreName + "/file.shp";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);

        request.ContentType = "application/zip";
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GEOSERVER_USER, GEOSERVER_PASSWD);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " +
                                                Convert.ToBase64String(
                                                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GEOSERVER_USER + ":" + GEOSERVER_PASSWD)));

        // byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(@fileUri);
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(localShapeFile, 0, localShapeFile.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


        return false;

    }
```

Comment: What value are you using for workspace?

Comment: An alphanumeric string. In the example it is "deletemequick". I am trying to preview inside geoserver. Also it seems like I don't have projection info.